# Ubuntu, then Windows 7 was installed, how to switch them?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

Sorry if I asking old question.

I had only ubuntu on my laptop, then I installed Windows 7 on other partition. I thought that I will be choosing OS when computer boots, but it always loads Windows 7 and don't give any choose option.

From ancient times it was normal to have XP, then install Linux, it always give choose option, but now I don't know how to configure that things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot to a live cd.  Load up the system under "Try ubuntu".  Open a terminal.  Type `sudo install /dev/sd?` replacing the ? with the proper letter of the main drive (this will likely be an `a`, resulting in `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`).

Afterwards, reboot without the LiveCD and see if Grub shows up.  Lemme know if it doesn't because I have another method that worked for me.

Comment: Just a tidbit of info: When you install Windows alongside a preexisting Ubuntu installation, Windows will overwrite (or take control of, depending on the setup) of the boot loader. To override this, you need to reinstall the Grub bootloader.  Then you can effectively dual boot.  Usually, what you'd do is install Windows first, then Ubuntu, because then the bootloader is fixed to be Grub.

Comment: tried to do with your suggestions, but it always gives an error:
install: missing destination file operand after '/dev/sda3
try install --help' for more information.

Comment: dont specify the partition at all.  Only specify the drive device itself `sda`, not `sda3`.